# C++ implicit conversion string to char

Tags: c++

I got the following code

File **c_header.h**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
#endif
void Do_Some_String_Operation(const char* const pString);

#ifdef __cplusplus
 }
#endif
```

This code is included in a cpp file.

File **cpp_file.cpp**

```
#include "c_header.h"
void main()
{
    Do_Some_String_Operation("my_nice_string");
}
```

The Problem here is, that the argument is treated as a string by Default. Since the function only takes a char * the Compiler warns me about an implicit converion string => char.

How can i tell the Compiler to treat the Argument as a char*. I tried

```
Do_Some_String_Operation(static_cast<char*>("my_nice_string"));
```

But that did not make the warning disappear. :(

Comment: [mcve] please. That function accepts a `const char*`. There is nothing invalid in the snippets you show about it.

Comment: the second const makes the pointer itself a const, sort of like doing func(const int) except in this case, the const is applied to the pointer. The function is fine. The cast should not be needed.

Comment: Show the exact error message from the compiler please

Comment: the excact error message is: "ISO C++ forbids converting a string to char* "

Answer (score 3):

Your code is well-formed and it compiles without errors.

---

As a side note, you may like to remove the top level `const` in the function *declaration*:

```
void Do_Some_String_Operation(const char* pString);
```

That top level `const` is function's implementation detail and should not leak into its interface. You can add that `const` in the function *definition*.